# I'm trying to query the customer name with an apostrophe but it looks like a special character?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with the T-SQL database example for the book Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan. (http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tsqlfund2012/)

I'm trying to query the customer name O’Brien, Dave but it is turning into a challenge. The apostrophe is not the apostrophe on my keyboard. It is not the ` on my keyboard either. I tried searching the character map for it and came up empty too. How do I type that character? How would I put it in a LIKE statement?

Thanks

EDIT: here is the content of the **NVARCHAR** field

```
'O’Brien, Dave'
```

I've enclosed the entire name in the single quote I have on my keyboard. As you can see it is different. I believe it's because the column type is NVARCHAR. But I don't know how to query this?

This query does not return the record:

```
SELECT [custid]
  ,[companyname]
  ,[contactname]  
 FROM [TSQL2012_Jones].[Sales].[Customers] where contactname = N'O''Brien, Dave'
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your query attempts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to Query text in access with an apostrophe in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764197/sql-to-query-text-in-access-with-an-apostrophe-in-it)

Comment: Duplicate Question Answered

 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764197/sql-to-query-text-in-access-with-an-apostrophe-in-it
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509159/how-do-i-search-for-names-with-apostrophe-in-sql-server

Comment: Bryan Swan, this is not a duplicate question. As you can see from the SQL I added to the original post, I know how to query an apostrophe using 2 single quotes. To test my code please go to the link provided, download the book's source code and run the tsql2012.sql file to create the sample database I speak of.  Thanks

Comment: FYI, if you ever need to know what a particular character is, slap it into the `UNICODE(N'{funky_character}')` function as follows: `SELECT UNICODE(N'’'), NCHAR(8217);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that apostrophe is unicode character `%u2019`.
you can get that character using `nchar()` function

```
...
where contactname = N'O' + nchar(0x2019) + 'Brien, Dave'
```

[unicode escaping tool](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php)

Comment: or you can use the literal string directly: `N'O’Brien, Dave'`

Comment: This correct as well as srutzky's comment off the main question. Thanks to you both! Here's a link I found showing the Hex and Decimal value for the "right single quotation mark"... http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x2019/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [custid]
  ,[companyname]
  ,[contactname]  
 FROM [TSQL2012_Jones].[Sales].[Customers] where contactname LIKE N'O_Brien, Dave'
```